# Relationship between extinction coefficient and the imaginary refraction index

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, experimental-physics, material-science, simulations

I'm trying to add an ITO glass material made by SPI to an FDTD Lumerical simulation. For that I need the real and imaginary parts of the refractive index. In their website though, they give the real part of the refractive index for their ITO glass, and the extinction coefficient:
https://www.2spi.com/ito-tech-data/

What is the relationship between extinction coefficient and the imaginary refractive index? I know there is a relationship between the imaginary refractive index and absorption coefficient. Is it the same thing as extinction coefficient though?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extinction coefficient is the imaginary component of refractive index.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I wanted to know. Even though I would have been happy if it was a bit more detailed with the difference between extinction and absorption coefficient.